# Is this buffer overrun error wrong or am I blind?

Tags: c, visual-studio, file, buffer, static-analysis

I have some simple code that is generating a warning for seemingly no reason:

```
// Get the length of the file, with overflow protection
size_t FileLength = GetFileLength(InputFile);
if (FileLength + 1 == 0) return 0;

// Allocate memory and format it as a string
char* FileContents = (char*)malloc(FileLength + 1);
if (FileContents == 0) return 0;
FileContents[FileLength] = 0;
size_t ContentsCursor = 0;

// Copy characters one by one until the measured length is reached
char Character;
while (ContentsCursor != FileLength) {
    Character = fgetc(InputFile);
    FileContents[ContentsCursor] = Character;
    ContentsCursor++;
}
```

I see no problem with this code, I even added some overflow protection at the top.
However, I get this code analysis warning:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'FileContents':  the writable size is 'FileLength+1' bytes, but '2' bytes might be written. RanDat  D:\OtherStuff\Programs\C - C++\RanDat   D:\OtherStuff\Programs\C - C++\RanDat\FileFunctions.h   82
```

Edit:
Forgot to add, I see no case in which the allocation length is less than 2 where it would write 2 bytes. After all, it only writes up to "FileLength", which is always one less than the length of the allocation.

Comment: There are many dozens of posts on Stack Overflow about this MSVC warning: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C6386

Comment: Steam Ranger, Why "Copy characters one by one until the measured length is reached" instead of `fread()`?  "I see no problem with this code" --> yet code never checks for errors from `fgetc(InputFile)`.

Comment: Casting the result of malloc on MSVC might be problematic, since it's still some manner of C90 compiler. I wouldn't trust it to give correct diagnostics in case of a missing `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Errors with `fgetc()` would never cause this problem. At most they'd result in a string full of garbage, but it would still be a valid string. Also, good idea I'd forgotten about `fread()`, thanks!

Comment: In trying to solve this mystery, simply trying to remove other deficiencies.  Tip: for future issues best to post a [mcve].